# Complex Analysis - Calculating Residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am told to calculate the residue of $ \frac{ e^{-z} }{ (z-1)^{2} } $ at $ z = 1 $. The answer is supposed to be $ \frac{ 1 }{ e } $.

Can someone give me a hint on how to approach this?

Comment: I'm not sure who told you it should be $e^{-1}$, but they were off by a factor of $-1$.

Comment: Do you know the formula to find residue for the function with pole of order $m$ at a given point , in particularly for pole of order $2$ ? See that the function has a double pole at $z=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note the Taylor series for $e^{-z}$ around the point $z=1$ is

$$e^{-1} - e^{-1}(z-1)+{e^{-1}(z-1)^2\over 2}-e^{-1}{(z-1)^3\over 6}+\ldots.$$

Dividing all terms by $(z-1)^2$ we get the Laurent series for ${e^{-z}\over (z-1)^2}$ centered at $z=1$:

> $${e^{-z}\over (z-1)^2}={e^{-1}\over (z-1)^2}-{e^{-1}\over (z-1)}+{e^{-1}\over 2}-{e^{-1}(z-1)\over 6}+\ldots$$

so the residue is $-e^{-1}$ by definition (i.e. coefficient $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent series).

This is confirmed by Cauchy's integral formula and the residue theorem (another way to get the answer besides the definition via the Laurent series).

> $$f^{(n)}(\xi)={n!\over 2\pi i}\oint_C{f(z)\over (z-\xi)^{n+1}}\,dz,\quad {1\over 2\pi i}\oint_C g(z)=\text{Res}(g, z_0)$$

with $z_0=1$ and $C$ a small curve around $z_0=1$, with $g(z)={e^{-z}\over (z-1)^2}$, $f(z)=e^{-z}$, $n=1$ since the derivative of $f$ at $z_0=1$ is $-e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

$Res(f;z=1)=\frac{d}{dz}\left\{(z-1)^2\frac{e^{-z}}{(z-1)^2}\right\}_{z=1}=\frac{d}{dz}(e^{-z})|_{z=1}=-e^{-1}$.